# What is the approach I should take to make a Kakuro grid?

Tags: android, user-interface, grid

I'm creating a Kakuro game for Android and it mainly consists of a large grid which contains only black and white squares according to a pattern. I have decided to use a custom class extended from `Button` to represent black and white squares.

But the problem is, I can't figure out what to use and/or extend to represent the square-containing (`Button`-containing) grid. It should have the following behavior:

- Should be able to house `Button`s along both x- and y-axes.
- Should be scrollable in both ways as the grid will most definitely exceed the device's screen size.
- Should not be too hard on the memory footprint.

So after some thinking, I have decided to create a custom class that extends `View`. But  I don't know exactly which methods to override to obtain the behavior I want.

So can anyone please tell me which methods I should override to obtain the behavior I need? (The behavior is somewhat similar to that of Minesweeper).

Or is there any other easier/faster method I can use?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if it is a grid you want, I recommend the [`GridView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView.html).

> A view that shows items in two-dimensional scrolling grid. The items
>   in the grid come from the ListAdapter associated with this view.

`GridView` tutorial: http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gridview.html

Comment: But is it scrollable in both directions? If not, which methods should I implement to get that functionality? The grid should work like a grid in Minesweeper games..

Answer (score 0):

Extending the GridView seems more suitable for your need: http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-gridview.html

Comment: But is it scrollable in both directions? If not, which methods should I implement to get that functionality?

Comment: Tough noogies. All the inbuilt Android layouts and Views apparently seem to have a tough time scrolling both ways. All the TableLayout, GridView, gallery etc seemt to do gr8 with only one way scrolling. Putting the GridView inside HorizintalScrollView "doesn't" work.   I would have solved the problem differently.  See the following two comments for details:

Comment: Method 1: I would have had a single flat screen and then would have drawn the Grid using the drawing functions and then maintaining a "Logical grid" in the backend to represent the board state.

Comment: Method 2:  If I have to use something like the in-built GridView which has only Vertical scrolling, I would have achieved the horizontal scrolling by maintaining the Actual board state in a logical grid in the backend and then sliding the contents of the backend array into the GridView. This way the GridView behaves like a sliding window or horizontal moving viewport into the real logical grid.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But I think you should add your three comments as part of your answer.. Just click *edit* at the bottom of your answer and type it there.